# Does the continuationTimeout in Camel Jetty can be used to mitigate Slow HTTP Dos Attacks?

Tags: security, http, jetty, ddos

According to the description for continuationTimeout in http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html,
I try to configure a Endpoint jetty:http://www.example.com:4000/xxxHttpService/?continuationTimeout=30000
to mitigate Slow HTTP DoS Attacks.

I expect if a client cannot send a HTTP request header in 30s, the Camel Jetty will disconnect with client. But when I use below python code to test, seems continuationTimeout does not work for mitigate Slow HTTP Dos Attacks.

```
CRLF = "\r\n"
xoh_hostname = '127.0.0.1'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.connect((xoh_hostname, 4000))
s.send("POST /xxxHttpService/ HTTP/1.1%sCache-Control: no-store%s" % (CRLF, CRLF))
starttime = time.time()
data = (s.recv(4096))
endtime = time.time()
print "The seconds Camel Jetty wait for a complete HTTP request header are %s" % str(endtime-starttime)
s.shutdown(1)
s.close()
print 'Received data: ', repr(data)
```

And the result is something like:

**The seconds Camel Jetty wait for a complete HTTP request header are 200.741626024

Received data:  ''**

So seems the default timeout Camel Jetty used wait for a complete HTTP request is 200s.
Does the continuationTimeout in Camel Jetty can be used to mitigate Slow HTTP Dos Attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the right configuration. It is not **continuationTimeout**, but **maxIdleTime** can be used to mitigate Slow HTTP DoS Attacks.

I set it in code as below:

```
JettyHttpComponent jettyComponent = getContext().getComponent("jetty", JettyHttpComponent.class);
Map<String, Object> socketConnectorProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
socketConnectorProperties.put("maxIdleTime", "50000"); //set timeout is 50s 
jettyComponent.setSocketConnectorProperties(socketConnectorProperties);
```

And then test as below, it passed testing as expect.

```
[root@clab295node10 ~]# python mytest.py
The seconds Camel Jetty wait for a complete HTTP request header are 50.6753239632
```

You can find the description for **maxIdleTime** in below link:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Jetty are you using. But considering [this documentation](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Connectors), It seems that you use a mix between maxIdleTime, lowResourcesConnections and lowResourcesMaxIdleTime.

According to documentation, the maxIdleTime will be used for normal connections, when the lowResourcesConnections is reached, then jetty will switch to use the value hold on lowResourcesMaxIdleTime.

Take a look over at [this link](https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008RseCAE) for further information.

I haven't tested myself yet. But I will do it shortly.